# Executing C programs from HDD or PenDrive

Tags: command-line, permissions, usb-drive, ntfs

So lately I've been in C programming. On trial and Error and Basis I tried Compiling(GCC) and Executing(./a.out) from my Windows' partition and Pen-drive i.e. precisely I tried executing on NTFS and FAT. I'm currently using Ubuntu 14.04(32bit) and executing via Terminal.

> PROBLEM:- When I tried executing C program in Terminal (in Pendrive), It returns a following error

```
bash: ./a.out: Permission denied
```

Here's what I tried:

**(1)WITHOUT ROOT-**

```
tj@tj-HP-Pavilion-dv4-Notebook-PC:/media/tj/HP/TJbin$ gcc phil.c -pthread -o dine
tj@tj-HP-Pavilion-dv4-Notebook-PC:/media/tj/HP/TJbin$ ./dine
bash: ./dine: Permission denied
```

**(2)WITH ROOT-**

```
root@tj-HP-Pavilion-dv4-Notebook-PC:/media/tj/HP/TJbin# gcc phil.c -pthread -o dine
root@tj-HP-Pavilion-dv4-Notebook-PC:/media/tj/HP/TJbin# ./dine  
bash: ./dine: Permission denied
```

**Explanation-**
Since without root, it returned an error "Permission denied"; I tried it with root, but no success.

**Question-**

1. Is it necessary that an C program must reside on EXT partition?
2. Is there any command that will grant the permission?
3. Does it need *.exe* for NTFS or FAT and if so can it be executed in Terminal?

Comment: Moreover, sometime pluggable devices are mounted explicitly `noexec` (and `nosuid, nodev`) for safety reasons. Although it seems that lately it's not the case anymore...

Comment: No @muru , I checked the output file's permission it belongs to *me* (Command ls -l). Later I tried it by giving it to *root* still no success!

Comment: What does that have to do with anything?